# How to Authenticate and Get Reports from Google Analytics to iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, gdata-api

How to Authenticate and Get Reports from Google Analytics to my custom iphone application.

I just want to Authenticate the User and get the registered URLs from Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GData Static library for Objective-C

you can find it here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client

You can see that one of the links is for analytics.

Here you can find a good tutorial for linking the library:

[Kelvin's blog - GData Objective-C Client Setup in Xcode 4](https://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/)

If you are using ARC, here is an update for the Header files so you can integrate them in your project with out getting ARC warnings:

[Updating Gdata library for ARC](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/source/detail?r=90)

And this is a simplified explanation I made for the ARC problem:

[explanation on the update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300030/gdata-static-library-exclude-files-from-arc-with-fno-objc-arc/8300527#8300527)

Comment: Link to r=90 is redirecting and not available on archive.org