# disabling ARC for .h files iphonesdk

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting, gdata-api

My projects uses ARC and I want to use GDATA api which is not ARC Compatible.
I know how to disable ARC for single file(by adding the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for those files). But in GDataObject.h file there is a structure defenition as

```
typedef struct GDataDescriptionRecord {
    NSString *label;
    NSString *keyPath;
    enum GDataDescRecTypes reportType;
} GDataDescriptionRecord;
```

It causes an error like

```
ARC forbids object in struct or union
```

How can I avoid this problem.
Is there any ARC compatible GDATA api available or any way to disable arc for .h files

Comment: possible duplicate of [GData static library- Exclude files from ARC with -fno-objc-arc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300030/gdata-static-library-exclude-files-from-arc-with-fno-objc-arc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define ARC_MEMBER __unsafe_unretained
#else
#define ARC_MEMBER 
#endif
```

Then, your structure would look something like this:

```
typedef struct GDataDescriptionRecord {
    ARC_MEMBER NSString *label;
    ARC_MEMBER NSString *keyPath;
    enum GDataDescRecTypes reportType;
} GDataDescriptionRecord;
```