# How to handle non-ARC code in header file?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, boost, automatic-ref-counting

My project structure

```
MainProject (ARC)
    SubProject(Non-ARC)
        Boost library(i.e. Popular C++ library here is a link http://www.boost.org/)
```

**Problem :**
    One of header file(`intrusive_ptr.h`) of Boost library has a inline function with "retain" statement(That file is edited by someone and it is working fine in "SubProject(Non-ARC)"). That header file is public, many files of subporjects are imported in "MainProject" and those file has a reference of this header file. So, indirectly that file comes in MainProject which is an ARC based. That's why compiler refuse to compile.

**What I know or tried:**
I know how to set the non ARC flag but that we can set only for `.m` file(compilable file only) not on `.h` file. if somebody could help me or suggest me any out of box solution.

For the persons who are interested in seeing the `"intrusive_ptr.h"` can find here [intrusive_ptr.h](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10719425). This file is a part of `boost` library so, suggestion should consider this library as well.

Any help or directions will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "one of header files of Boost library has a inline function with "retain" statement"??  No it doesn't...it is C++ so why would it?  I had a look and I didn't find what you were talking about.  I have to assume either you edited the file, you are talking about a different file, or you got the file from some place weird.  Which?

Comment: @borrrden: You are correct that file is edited by someone and it is working fine in "SubProject(Non-ARC)". I can compile and run it without an issue.

Comment: I guess you will have to do something like this then -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895144/disabling-arc-for-h-files-iphonesdk

Comment: @borrrden: Your trick worked. If you can answer the question then please I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the preprocessor to alter your header file using the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935354/1155387)

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
//ARC-specific things
#else
//Non-ARC specific things
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need Boost facility in some classes you can hide that using Objective-C++. Helper links: 
http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA45902?viewlocale=en_US